# Why does Express serve static files using middleware instead of other ways?

Tags: django, express, static-files

I'm a Django developer. In Django we use an application to serve staticfiles. Then I found that in Express we use a middleware. Could anyone explain what are the pros and cons of both methods?

Comment: Django and Express are quite different, you can't compare them directly.

Comment: @robertklep Actually I'm not comparing Django and Express. I'm just comparing different ways of serving static files. The key is not about any web frameworks.

Comment: You are assuming that both "apps" and "middleware" mean the same for both frameworks, which they don't. It's not possible to list pros and cons of both methods because they are different things, and besides, it borders on asking for opinion-based answers.

Comment: @robertklep Now I got your point! Thank you for the explanation.